# Find a functions such $\int_0^{1} |f(t) + g(t)| dt = 1$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, functions

I'm trying to find different continuous functions $f,g$ such that:

$\int_0^1|f(t)| dt = 1$

$\int_0^1|g(t)| dt = 1$

and

$\int_0^1|f(t) + g(t)| dt = 1$

I tried a lot of possiblities but I end up with nothing. I tried to firsly choose $\int_0^1|f(t) + g(t)| dt = 1$ and then try to find $f$ and $g$, but I wasn't able to do so. Do dsuch functions exist ?

Comment: What if you take $f$ symmetric about $1/2$ (so $f(1/2+x)=f(1/2-x)$) and $g$ inversely symmetric (so $g(1/2+x)=-g(1/2-x)$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $f(x)=2x-2$ and $g(x)=2x$ works.

Answer (score 1):

Another one that could maybe work is $f(x) = (2+\sqrt{3})x-\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and
$g(x)= - (2+\sqrt{3})x + \frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Those would be symmetric around $\frac{1}{2}$ and have an integral of $\frac{3}{4}$ above the x-axis and $\frac{1}{4}$ below.